# Frictional drag coefficient for flat plate normal to a uniform flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, drag

In the case of a flat plate perpendicular to a uniform flow, it is commonly understood that for high Reynolds numbers, the drag coefficient ($C_D$) is known to be around 2.0. While many references in the literature suggest that the drag coefficient is exclusively attributed to pressure drag, the Falkner-Skan solution contradicts this notion. This solution provides a non-dimensional shear stress value of 1.233 for the scenario of a normal flat plate (specifically, a 2-dimensional stagnation problem).

Utilising this shear stress value, it becomes possible to derive a formula for the frictional drag coefficient associated with the normal flat plate. This implies that even in cases where pressure drag dominates due to flow separation, a supplementary contribution exists from frictional drag.

In essence, the question can be succinctly put: Does the drag acting on a normal flat plate arise solely from pressure drag, or does it also encompass a minor component from weak frictional drag?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the drag is the force component parallel to the oncoming flow. Any frictional forces that may occur would be acting along the surface of the plate, and therefore wouldn't contribute to the drag.

The Faulkner-Scan solution is an extension of flat-plate boundary-layer theory to wedge-shaped objects with relatively small angles and should not be applied to cases with angles approaching ninety degrees.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, but the frictional forces play role as well.

Comment: The shear stresses are in the wrong direction (for this geometry) to contribute directly to the drag, but the energy they remove from the flow could affect the pressure distributions, and thereby cause an increase in the drag (probably a small amount).